# what's the exact link to access Gerrit REST API?

Tags: rest, api, gerrit

I'm trying to use Gerrit in my project and I need to access this gerrit using REST API.

I checked the user guide at this page: https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api.html, but I am frustrated because I can't find the exact link address for the command line.

For example, I want to get the version info of the server, according to this link: https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-config.html, I use this command:

```
$ curl -4 -G --digest --user user:password https://gerrit.xxx.com/gerrit/a/server/config/version HTTP/1.0
Unauthorizedcurl: (7) Failed connect to HTTP:80; No route to host
$
```

If I use http instead of https, it's like this:

```
$ curl -4 -G --digest --user user:password http://gerrit.xxx.com/gerrit/a/server/config/version HTTP/1.0
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://gerrit.xxx.com/gerrit/a/server/config/version">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
curl: (7) Failed connect to HTTP:80; No route to host
$
```

while, TTT/PPP is a project which could be access from this url:

```
https://gerrit.xxx.com/gerrit/#/admin/projects/TTT/PPP
```

I'm almost mad of this, can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

To get the version info of the server execute the following:

```
curl -s --user USER:PASS --request GET https://GERRIT-SERVER/a/config/server/version
```